# Navigate in website with getElementByName

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to download an excel file from a website.  I have followed a few tutorials on here, but am having trouble.

My variables are publicially declared.  But as expected, when I get to `element.Click`, I get my error.  I know I am confusing the method/function that I am calling, and am hoping for a bit of help.  Thanks.

```
Public Sub testLogin()

Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

webSite = "https://na30.salesforce.com/00O36000006xEvX"
webSite = "my url here"

With objIE
    .Visible = True
    .navigate webSite
    Do While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4
        DoEvents
    Loop

    Set element = .document.getElementsByname("csvsetup")


End With

element.Click 'error happens here

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

`getElementsByname` returns a *collection* of elements - even if there's only one match for the name - so likely what you want is something like:

```
element(0).Click
```

depending on whether you have more than one match and the position of the element you want to click in the collection of returned matches. For example `(0)` would be the first match.

Comment: I really appreciate it.

Comment: Yeah, this is definitely my error.  I did not realize the return had a collection.  Now the tutorials make more sense with `(0)` portion.